# Issue on Positioning Transparent Image on The Top of another Using CSS rule

Tags: css

I am trying to overlay a transparent image on top of another at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qshd88g3/4/) using this css rule:

```
.item {
    position:relative;
}
.inner {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
.outer {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background: url(http://chocolate.dream-demo.com/wp/wp-content/themes/dt-chocolate/images/home-bg.png) repeat;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="http://www.timeshighereducation.co.uk/Pictures/web/y/c/g/win_lose_dic_450.jpg" />
    </div>
     <div class="outer"> </div>
</div>
```

but it is not working! I need to use the css way to be able to repeat the background since it is not same size as other one.
it is working on `position:fixed` format but it covers all the body content too!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By positioning both your `inner` and `outer` `div`s absolutely, their container has no height.

You need to make it so that `inner` pushes the height of `item` to the correct size.

To do this, change your css to look like this:

```
.item {
    position:relative;
}
.inner {
    position:relative;
}
.outer {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background: url(http://chocolate.dream-demo.com/wp/wp-content/themes/dt-chocolate/images/home-bg.png) repeat;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qshd88g3/5/)**